# Parsing an XML string containing "&#x20;" (which must be preserved)

Tags: .net-2.0, xml-parsing

I have code that is passed a `string` containing XML. This XML may contain one or more instances of `&#x20;` (an entity reference for the blank space character). I have a requirement that these references should not be resolved (i.e. they should *not* be replaced with an actual space character).

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Basically, given a string containing the XML:

```
<pattern value="[A-Z0-9&#x20;]" />
```

I do **not** want it to be converted to:

```
<pattern value="[A-Z0-9 ]" />
```

(What I am actually trying to achieve is to simply take an XML string and write it to a "pretty-printed" file. This is having the side-effect of resolving occurrences of `&#x20;` in the string to a single space character, which need to be preserved. The reason for this requirement is that the written XML document must conform to an externally-defined specification.)

I have tried creating a sub-class of `XmlTextReader` to read from the XML string and overriding the `ResolveEntity()` method, but this isn't called. I have also tried assigning a custom `XmlResolver`.

I have also tried, as suggested, to "double encode". Unfortunately, this has not had the desired effect, as the `&amp;` is *not* decoded by the parser. Here is the code I used:

```
string schemaText = @"...<pattern value=""[A-Z0-9&#x26;#x20;]"" />...";
XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.Indent = true;
writerSettings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
writerSettings.CloseOutput = true;
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
writerSettings.IndentChars = "\t";

StringBuilder writtenSchema = new StringBuilder();
using ( StringReader sr = new StringReader( schemaText ) )
using ( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( sr ) )
using ( TextWriter tr = new StringWriter( writtenSchema ) )
using ( XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create( tr, writerSettings ) )
{
   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument( reader );
   XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

   nav.WriteSubtree( writer );
}
```

The written XML ends up with:

```
<pattern value="[A-Z0-9&amp;#x20;]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be preserved, you need to double-encode it: `&amp;#x20;`. The XML-reader *will* translate entities, that's more or less how XML works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<pattern value="[A-Z0-9&#x26;#x20;]" />
```

What I did above is replaced "&" with "&#x26;" thereby escaping the ampersand.

Comment: `&amp;` is part of XML, and a spot more readable than `&#x26;`, use it wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for that. I used &#x26; because I was unsure if the named &amp; existed outside of HTML (in XML).

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get it to work. I have updated the Q - maybe you could have a look and point out where I am going wrong? Thanks